# Multiply two matrices in SML

Tags: sml, smlnj

I want to write a function in SML/NJ which will take 2 matrices as an arguments and it will multiply them.

I can only use:

- function dot, which take 2 vectors and calculate scalar product:

  ```
  fun dot (xs: int list, ys: int list): int =
      List.foldl (fn (x,y) => x+y)
         0
         (ListPair.map (fn (x,y) => x*y) (xs, ys))
  ```
- function transpose, which take 1 matrix and calculate transpose of this matrix:

  ```
  fun transpose (m: 'a list list): 'a list list =
      List.tabulate (List.length (List.nth (m, 0)),
             fn x => List.map (fn y => (List.nth (y, x))) m)
  ```

  - anonymous function
  - structures List, ListPair and Math

The function I want to write should be like this:

```
fun multiply (a: int list list, b: int list list): int list list
```

So far I have done this:

```
fun multiply (a: int list list, b: int list list): int list list =
case a of
[] => []
  | g::rep => [(List.map (fn y => dot(g, y)) transpose(b))] @ (multiply(rep, b))
```

But I got this error:

```
test.sml:66.21-66.62 Error: operator and operand do not agree [tycon mismatch]
  operator domain: int list list
  operand:         'Z list list -> 'Z list list
  in expression:
(List.map (fn y => dot <exp>)) transpose
```

I get no errors, if in the last line of function multiply I write b instead of tranpose(b), but of course, if I do this, I don't the the resoult I want:

```
fun multiply (a: int list list, b: int list list): int list list =
case a of
[] => []
  | g::rep => [(List.map (fn y => dot(g, y)) b)] @ (multiply(rep, b))
```

I don't know what else should I do. Can anybody pease help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There exists [a solution for OCaml on RosettaCode](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#OCaml) that you can translate.

Given the illustration,

```
         | [ a,   [ c,
         |   b ]    d ]
---------+-------------
[ 1, 2 ] |   w      x
[ 3, 4 ] |   y      z
```

then for each row in the first matrix, calculate the `dot` product with the same number *column* of the second matrix. I.e. `w = dot ([1, 2], [a, b])`. Extracting the rows of the first matrix is easy, since you can use list recursion.

Extracting the columns of the second matrix is less easy, because they are orthogonal to the list representation (i.e. `a` is the first element of the first row, `b` is the first element of the second row, `c` is the second element of the first row, and `d` is the second element of the second row.

You can simplify extracting columns from the second matrix by performing a `transpose` in which case extracting columns becomes equivalent to extracting rows. At this point you can take the pairwise `dot` product of "rows" (that is, rows in the first matrix and transposed columns ("rows") in the second matrix).

I would encourage the use of [`Array2`](http://sml-family.org/Basis/array2.html) for this type of operations, since you also avoid error handling when your "matrices" (lists) are jagged (have different row lengths).

Answer (score -1):

At least I succeeded using your scheme

```
exception dim_Error;

fun listPair (l1:int list) (l2:int list): (int * int) List.list =  
`if not (List.length l1 = List.length l2) then raise dim_Error
    else List.tabulate (List.length l1, fn i => (List.nth(l1, i),List.nth(l2, i)));`    

fun dotprod (l1:int list) (l2:int list): int = 
    List.foldl (fn (x,y) => x+y) 0 (map (fn (x,y) => x*y) (listPair l1 l2));

fun transpose (matrix: int list list):int list list =
    List.tabulate (List.length (List.nth (matrix, 0)), fn i => List.map (fn j => List.nth (j, i)) matrix);

fun multiply (matrix1: int list list) (matrix2: int list list): int list list =
case matrix1 of 
    [] => []
    |    x::xr => [List.map (fn y => dotprod x y) (transpose matrix2)] @ (multiply xr matrix2);

val A = [[ 21,  ~2,  3, ~1], [  2, 115,  6,  7], [ ~6,  9, 210, 11], [ 13, 14, ~19, 15], [ ~2, 21, ~99,  3], [  5, ~4,  ~1,  9]];
val B = [[2, ~6, 0, 3, 9], [~4, ~1, 2, 1, ~2], [~6, 5, 3, ~5, 1], [10, 9, ~4, 9, ~7]];
val C = [[~4, ~3, 7], [1, ~1, ~2], [~5, 3, 7], [8, ~7, 2], [~8, 3, 6]];

multiply (multiply  A B) C;
```

Comment: Is this an answer?