# How to Write a function vmProduct that multiple a row vector of size n with a matrix with n rows and m columns to produce a vector of size m in SML

Tags: sml

how to write a function that multiple a row vector of size n with a
matrix with n rows and m columns to produce a vector of size m. For
example, `([1,2,3], [[1,1], [2,1], [3,1]])` should return
`[14, 6]`.

I believe these two functions can be utilized:

```
fun vectorAdd(nil, _) = nil
  | vectorAdd(_, nil) = nil
  | vectorAdd(a1::first_list, a2::second_list) = 
    (a1 + a2) :: vectorAdd(first_list, second_list);

val q1_answer = vectorAdd([1,2,3], [4,5,2]);

fun svProduct(x, y) = 
  map (fn (item) => item * x) y;

val q2_answer = svProduct(2, [1,2,3]);
```

Comment: We won't do your homework for you. Please read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/16886597) and [this](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6166).  Please [edit] your post to show us what you have already tried. If you have a specific error or issue, we might be able to help, but we certainly won't do the entire assignment for you.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Write the result, `[1*1 + 2*2 + 3*3, 1*1 + 2*1 +3*1]`, as an addition of vectors, each of which is the product of a number and a vector. Then figure out how to express that recursively.

Comment: This may be useful reading: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53343634/multiply-two-matrices-in-sml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's get some things out of the way first:

```
exception UnmatchedLengths;

fun transpose([]) = []
  | transpose([[]]) = []
  | transpose([]::_) = []
  | transpose(lst) = List.map List.hd lst :: transpose(List.map List.tl lst);

fun map2(_, [], []) = []
  | map2(_, [], _) = raise UnmatchedLengths
  | map2(_, _, []) = raise UnmatchedLengths
  | map2(f, x::xs, y::ys) = f(x, y) :: map2(f, xs, ys);

fun sum lst = 
  List.foldl op+ 0 lst;
```

The `transpose` function takes a list of lists and transposes it. So in your example, `[[1,2,3], [[1,1], [2,1], [3,1]]` becomes `[[1, 2, 3], [1, 1, 1]]`.

The `map2` function takes a function that works on two lists and maps a function over their corresponding components. E.g.

```
map2(op+, [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6])
```

Evaluates to:

```
[5, 7, 9]
```

And `sum` is very self-explanatory, using `list.foldl` and `op+` to sum a list of ints.

### Putting it all together

Putting it all together we can create a function `m` that performs the calculation you're trying to achieve:

```
fun m(v, ma) = 
  let
    val t = transpose(ma)
    val combos = List.map (fn mi => (v, mi)) t
    val products = List.map (fn (a, b) => map2(op*, a, b)) combos 
  in
    List.map sum products
  end;
```

First we transpose the matrix. then we create a list of tuples of the vector and each row in the transposed matrix. In your example, we'd now have `[([1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]), ([1, 2, 3], [1, 1, 1])]`.

Next we map over those combos, using `map2` to do our multiplication.

In your example we'd now get `[[1, 4, 9], [1, 2, 3]]`.

The last step is simply to map `sum` to each of these, which leaves us with `[14, 6]`.